# Labels of vies (with id) don't change when configuration changes

Tags: android

*Sorry for my English.*

I have some activity.

Layout of the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/containerOfStandardFilters" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/containerOfMoreFilters" />


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

In code of activity I dynamically fill both of the container layouts. Currently I fill only `containerOfStandardFilters`.

Layout which I used to inflate content of `containerOfStandardFilters`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeOfFilterGroupTitle"
        android:text="@string/titleOfSortingGroup" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeOfSortingGroupItems"
        android:text="@string/labelOfSortByDistanceCheckBox"
        android:id="@+id/sortByDistanceCheckBox" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeOfSortingGroupItems"
        android:text="@string/labelOfSortByDiscountCheckBox"
        android:id="@+id/sortByDiscountCheckBox" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sizeBetweenFilterGroups" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeOfFilterGroupTitle"
        android:text="@string/titleOfPaymentMethodGroup"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeOfSortingGroupItems"
        android:text="@string/labelOfCashlessPaymentsCheckBox"
        android:id="@+id/cashlessPaymentsCheckBox" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sizeBetweenFilterGroups" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeOfFilterGroupTitle"
        android:text="@string/titleOfWorkingHoursGroup"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeOfSortingGroupItems"
        android:text="@string/labelOfWorksNowCheckBox"
        android:id="@+id/worksNowCheckBox" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sizeBetweenFilterGroups" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeOfFilterGroupTitle"
        android:text="@string/titleOfDiscountTypeGroup" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeOfSortingGroupItems"
        android:text="@string/labelOfBonusCheckBox"
        android:id="@+id/bonusCheckBox" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeOfSortingGroupItems"
        android:text="@string/labelOfDiscountCheckBox"
        android:id="@+id/discountCheckBox" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeOfSortingGroupItems"
        android:text="@string/labelOfCashBackCheckBox"
        android:id="@+id/cashBackCheckBox" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But if I change current language (via Settings) and returns to the filter activity (from system Settings activity) then only views without id will update labels.

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: The value of anything with an id is retained when configuration changes.Also,you could implement the code using fragments and add them in your xml instead of frame layouts

Answer (score 0):

*Sorry for my English.*

In the end I decided this issue as follows.

I wrapped each `View` with `text` and `id` attributes in a `FrameLayout` with the same `id` attribute and removed `id` from each such `View`.

But, the truth, the code for finding a `View` became more complicated.

In `layout` instead of using:

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/labelOfCheckBox"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox" />
```

I use:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox" >

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/labelOfCheckBox" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And the code to find wrapped `Views`:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public View findWrappedView(int id) {
        ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(id);
        return container.getChildAt(0);
    }
}
```